# Astuetz viewpager on android IceCream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm facing a little issue with Astuetz Viewpager on Icecream Sandwich.
The problem is that, while scrolling through pages, the page indicator and the date are not vanishing/changing color.
The same pager, on pre-honeycomb devices, is working like a charm.
Is anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

I've been analyzing the Astuetz viewpager library and i've found out that the onDraw method of the textview containing the date and the colored bottom border is not called while scrolling the page. We need to call the invalidate method on that extended textview's parent onLayout method.

Change the ViewPagerTabs class like this (add tab.invalidate() in the for looop)

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int count = getChildCount();

    final int center = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;

    // At this position, the centered tab will be highlighted via
    // ViewPagerTab.setCenterPercent(int percent)
    final int highlightOffset = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 5;

    // lay out each tab
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        final ViewPagerTab tab = (ViewPagerTab) getChildAt(i);
        tab.invalidate();
        final int tabCenter = tab.layoutPos + tab.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int diff = Math.abs(center - tabCenter);

        if (diff <= highlightOffset) {
            final int x1 = highlightOffset;
            final int y = (int) 100 * diff / x1;
            tab.setCenterPercent(100 - y);
        } else {
            tab.setCenterPercent(0);
        }

        tab.layout(tab.layoutPos, this.getPaddingTop(), tab.layoutPos + tab.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getPaddingTop()
            + tab.getMeasuredHeight());

    }

}
```